# Python Pandas GroupBy % calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a dataframe with 2 columns. I'm trying to calculate the % of TypeB on number of records in ID as follows:

Formula: (Count of TypeB) / (No of records in Group) * 100

```
Result :
001 = (2/3) * 100 => 66.66
002 = (0/2) * 100 => 0
003 = (1/1) * 100 => 100
```

Dataframe

```
ID   Type
001  TypeA
001  TypeB
001  TypeB
002  TypeA
002  TypeA
003  TypeB
```

So, far I've been able to groupBy

```
byID = df.groupby('ID')
```

I was reading panda's crosstab, but can't seem to figure out how to approach the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for count length of groups first, reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with filling `NaN` by `0` and then divide column `TypeB` by [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html), last multiple by `100`:

```
df = df.groupby(['ID','Type']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
Type  TypeA  TypeB
ID                
1         1      2
2         2      0
3         0      1

df1 = df.TypeB.div(df.sum(axis=1)).mul(100).reset_index(name='percentage')
print (df1)
   ID  percentage
0   1   66.666667
1   2    0.000000
2   3  100.000000
```

For reshape is possible use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html), but it is a bit slowier in larger dataframe:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df.ID,df.Type)
print (df)
Type  TypeA  TypeB
ID                
1         1      2
2         2      0
3         0      1
```

EDIT:

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) for adding new column:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['ID','Type']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
Type  TypeA  TypeB
ID                
1         1      2
2         2      0
3         0      1

df2 = df1.TypeB.div(df1.sum(axis=1)).mul(100)
print (df2)
ID
1     66.666667
2      0.000000
3    100.000000
dtype: float64

df['percentage'] = df.ID.map(df2)
print (df)
   ID   Type  percentage
0   1  TypeA   66.666667
1   1  TypeB   66.666667
2   1  TypeB   66.666667
3   2  TypeA    0.000000
4   2  TypeA    0.000000
5   3  TypeB  100.000000
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael - Would you please help explain the approach. I'd very much appreciate how you went about the solution.

Comment: Is it better? I add output of `df` after reshape.

Comment: thank you @jezrael it has helped me and now I need to find a way how to add this new 'percentage' column to every ID in the original dataframe. Ah! if only the docs would explain how you did. Much appreciated.

Comment: I add solution for add new column, maybe help too. And thank you for accepting!

Comment: thank you @jezrael, but I'm getting an error TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable while trying to map. Please note for brevity, I've reduced the no of columns of my original dataframe. It has a shape o (475,29). Does the no of columns matter in mapping?

Comment: I am not sure how you get your problem, but `map` function works only with `Series` (column of `df`), so it seems you map `df`, no column - `df.id`.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I though df('COL_NAME') is equal to writing df.COL_NAME => guess I was wrong. Thank you it's now solved .

Comment: You are close - `df['COL_NAME']` is same as `df.COL_NAME `

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` with `value_counts(normalize=True)`
`normalize` will automatically divide counts by totals.

```
df.groupby('ID').Type.value_counts(normalize=True).unstack(fill_value=0).TypeB

ID
001    0.666667
002    0.000000
003    1.000000
Name: TypeB, dtype: float64
```

Comment: thank you @piRSquared this also works. But I can only accept one answer.